# updating an attibute on ruby on rails associated object with the has one association error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Please I need your help. I tried to update an attribute on a table but it is not updating. below is a run of the code.

user = User.find(7)
  User Load (4.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]

login_details = user.login_detail
login_details = user.login_detail
  LoginDetail Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "login_details".* FROM "login_details" WHERE "login_details"."user_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["user_id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]

login_details.status = 1
login_details.status = 1
1
login_details.save
login_details.save
   (1.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
true

The user has one login detail.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your login_details object doesn't have status = 1 already? If it's true ActiveRecord not start database query.

Comment: No. status is 0

Comment: what `login_details.valid?` returns?

Comment: It returned true

Comment: please show your models code and tables (schema.rb)

Comment: class LoginDetail < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 before_save {self.status = 0}
end

Comment: class LoginDetail < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 before_save {self.status = 0}
end

Comment: class LoginDetail < ApplicationRecord  
 belongs_to :user  
 before_save {self.status = 0}  
end

Comment: before_save {self.status = 0}   - this is the answer, you set status but your callback changes it to zero again and you see no changes.

Comment: np) rate me pls

Comment: Please. How do I get the default status to zero when a new record is saved?

Comment: 2 ways: 1) default value into database 2) after_initialize :fill_status ; def fill_status; status = 0 if status.nil? ;end

Comment: please how do i rate. I am new to stackoverflow

Comment: up arrow near my answer, is it clickable?